# Btrfs Quotas for Hierarchy in Filesystem

Tags: filesystem, btrfs

I want to implement a hierarchy of quotas in my filesystem. I will show you an example:

```
Folder A has Folder A1 and A2.
  A
 /  \
A1   A2
```

A should have a quota(limit) 10GB
A1 should have a quota(limit) 10GB
A2 should have a quota(limit) 5GB

So I want that my system doesnt allow me to put more data into A1 and A2 than A can handle, for example A2=5GB and A1=6GB should not be allowed and the quotas for the lower levels should be working as well.
It could also be that we only have a limit for A and for A2. So A1 can be as big as it needs to be but not bigger than A allows it.

After hours of research my filesystem is not working how I wanted it too. If I list my subvolumes, everything is at level 5, I dont know if this is correct or not.

Can someone show me an example how you can do this or how should I proceed.

Best regards Eugen

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer, I will post my example code for creating a Parent\Sub hierarchy.
If someone has any questions you can ask me here, I will try to answer them.

```
    sudo mkdir test


sudo btrfs subvolume create test/a
sudo btrfs subvolume create test/b
sudo btrfs subvolume create test/c
sudo btrfs subvolume create test/d


sudo btrfs qgroup limit 5M test/a
sudo btrfs qgroup limit 6M test/b
sudo btrfs qgroup limit 7M test/c
sudo btrfs qgroup limit 8M test/d

sudo btrfs qgroup create 1/1 test/
sudo btrfs qgroup limit 15M 1/1 test/

sudo btrfs qgroup assign 0/278 1/1 test/
sudo btrfs qgroup assign 0/279 1/1 test/
sudo btrfs qgroup assign 0/280 1/1 test/
sudo btrfs qgroup assign 0/281 1/1 test/


##TEST##
sudo cp ~/file4MB /test/a/4MB
sudo cp ~/file4MB /test/b/4MB
sudo cp ~/file4MB /test/c/4MB
sudo cp ~/file4MB /test/d/4MB
cp: error writing '/test/d/4MB': Disk quota exceeded

ls -lh test/a
total 4.0M
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4.0M Oct 18 12:22 4MB
ls -lh test/b
total 4.0M
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4.0M Oct 18 12:23 4MB
ls -lh test/c
total 4.0M
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4.0M Oct 18 12:23 4MB
ls -lh test/d
total 2.9M                                          
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.9M Oct 18 12:23 4MB
```